# read only csv files python

Tags: python, csv

I can read all `csv` files like this in python:

```
import glob
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print files
```

However I only want to read the files that have just `.csv` as suffix. For example
I would only wanna read

`file.csv` and not

```
file.x.csv
```

or

```
file.x.y.csv
```

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Variable name `files` as used in `for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):` is misleading as `files` refers to a single file name...

Comment: This question is very misleading: it is **not about** reading files, or about the CSV format at all. It is **purely** about *verifying file names*, i.e., *checking the content of strings*. It is almost certainly a duplicate of something, and a poor signpost at that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use `count`

```
import glob
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    # print all files that contain only .csv
    if files.count('.') == 1:
       print files
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a guard like

```
if '.' not in os.path.basename(files)[:-4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that matches .csv at the end of each string, filename is a variable for a string with the .csv at the end.

```
import re

if re.search('\.csv', filename):
     do something
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter()` and a regex.

```
import glob
import re

flt = re.compile(r'^[^.]+\.csv$',re.I)
for f in filter(flt.match,glob.glob('*.csv')):
    print(f)
```

The regex here assumes that there is only a single period in the file name. Your needs might require a different regex.